# Visual composer post grid loading very slowly

Tags: wordpress

visual composer post grid is loading too slow, my post takes over 45 secs to load,  all the other part of the page will load fast but the very section for the post takes time to come up. 
Here is the website link for you to see www.chiomaokpara.com

Comment: because you are loading all of your posts and categories together, posts of a specific category should be loaded upon clicking on the category

Comment: Thanks, so how can i load specific category first and disable the load all post filter

Comment: check if it has lazy loading option

Comment: It does not have lazy loading option